# Custom Program - IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

`this has been bugging me .giving me error.....can anyone tell me how to solve that:
exception in thread "main"  StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8'

```
   public class Solution {
   public static boolean checkit(String input){
       int i,j;
       boolean s=false;
       for(i=0;i<=input.length()-3;i++){
           for(j=i+2;j<=input.length()-1;j++)
           {
               if(input.charAt(i)==input.charAt(j+1) && input.charAt(i+1)==input.charAt(j))
                   s=true;

           }
       }
     return s;  
   }
   public static void main(String [] args){

       System.out.print(checkit("ABcBAxxs"));

}
}
```

Comment: on which line? it means you are trying to get the char at index 8, while the String has (max) 8 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having

> ```
>       for(j=i+2;j<=input.length()-1;j++)
>       {
>           if(input.charAt(i)==input.charAt(j+1) && input.charAt(i+1)==input.charAt(j))
> ```

when *j* values *input.length()-1* then *input.charAt(j+1)* access at *input.length()* so out of your String

---

Out of that, when *s* become *true* it is useless to continue to loop because *s* cannot become *false* back. You can remove your variable *s*, replace *s=true;* by *return true;* and *return s;* by *return false;*

Comment: ok i get it now..... about your comment actually it was just a code for checking occurrence of BA for AB if present return true...its solved now.....thnks